# How to add a circle end point to ProgressBar.js Semi Circle

Tags: reactjs, geometry, progress-bar

I created the semi circle using progressbar.js in reactjs. And get the semi circle like this.

[image]

I want to make it like this image.

[image]

How to do that using reactjs ?

Below is my code

```
new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(`#container-${id}`, {
      strokeWidth: 10,
      trailColor: "#191C26",
      trailWidth: 10,
      easing: "easeInOut",
      duration: 1400,
      svgStyle: {
        stroke: "#"+randomColor,
      },
      text: {
        value: "",
        alignToBottom: false,
      },

      // Set default step function for all animate calls
      step: (state, bar) => {
        bar.path.setAttribute("stroke", state.color); 
        },
    });

   
     bar.animate(meter);
```

I want to change the appeareance of the image like this, with giving a circle ending point

[image]